# Pandas column of non-unique lists into column names with filled entries

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `data:`

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"col1" : ['1_xy','2_xy','3_xy','4_xy','5_xy'], 
                     "col2" : [['a', 'b', 'c'], 
                               ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'], 
                               ['a', 'j', 'k'], 
                               ['a', 'b', 'd'], 
                               ['a', 'l', 'm']]})
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2
0   1_xy    [a, b, c]
1   2_xy    [d, e, f, g, h, i]
2   3_xy    [a, j, k] 
3   4_xy    [a, b, d]
4   5_xy    [a, l, m]
```

I am trying to convert this dataframe into one that looks like this:

```
import re
new_data = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['1_xy','2_xy','3_xy','4_xy','5_xy'],
                     'a' : [1,0,1,1,1], 'b' : [1,0,0,1,0],
                     'c' : [1,0,0,0,0], 'd' : [0,1,0,1,0],
                     'e' : [0,1,0,0,0], 'f' : [0,1,0,0,0],
                     'g' : [0,1,0,0,0], 'h' : [0,1,0,0,0],
                     'i' : [0,1,0,0,0], 'j' : [0,0,1,0,0],
                     'k' : [0,0,1,0,0], 'l' : [0,0,0,0,1],
                     'm' : [0,0,0,0,1]})
new_data[["col1"] + [name for name in new_data.columns if not re.search("col1", name)]]
```

Output:

```
    col1    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m
0   1_xy    1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   2_xy    0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
2   3_xy    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
3   4_xy    1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   5_xy    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
```

i.e. the columns of the new dataframe consists of the unique values found in the lists from `data.col2`, and values are filled with ones corresponding to an entry in the list.

So far, I have been playing around with `pandas.get_dummies`, but it creates spurious columns that I have no control over.

The real data I am trying to perform this operation on is very tall (many rows), so memory "might" be an issue, but all solutions are welcome. I should add that I have a workaround ready, which uses dictionary methods - but it is painfully slow, unfortunately. Hope anyone has seen this problem before and can be of assistance.

I am currently using python v3.4 and pandas v0.14.1 (I know...)

Comment: How do you use `get_dummies`?

Comment: @IanS I use it like this: df = data["col2"].str.get_dummies(sep=","), and sometimes it seemingly works, but I keep spotting duplicate columns that don't even match each other (which I assume should be expected, and I am using the command in the wrong way.) I should note that I haven't tried that command on my toy example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try get_dummies, by playing on parameters to have correct columns names:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(data.col2.apply(pd.Series), prefix='', prefix_sep='')
pd.concat([data['col1'], df], axis=1)

Out[31]:
   col1  a  d  b  e  j  l  c  d  f  k  m  g  h  i
0  1_xy  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  2_xy  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  1
2  3_xy  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
3  4_xy  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  5_xy  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however it throws a ValueError exception when I try it. Which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: version 0.15.2, is it on the apply or get_dummies that you have the issue?

Comment: 'apply' works for me (I have been following this path myself recently, it returns something promising.) It's the get_dummies that throws the exception. I get: "TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable". I think I might have to play around with types -- or am I mistaken?

Comment: I should also say that I get the following as well: "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,6) into shape (5)"

Comment: I switched to another version of pandas (0.16.2) and then it worked for me. Seems like this is a version specific issue with pandas. I am unsure whether to accept your answer, even though it does work for more mature versions of pandas. My own thoughts tend to converge to yes...